# R: xml2, extracting datasource names

Tags: regex, xml, r

I just installed the package XML2, and I manage to extract the aimed information. The next step is to 'visualize' the extracted information, e.g. with RShiny. Alas I fail to do "string parsing" correctly ...

For example: the extracted datasources

```
xmlfile <- read_xml("~ /Sample.xml")
ds <- xml_find_all(xmlfile , ".//datasource")
listds <- unique(unlist(ds, use.names = FALSE))
```

Datasources are (in this example) two excel files. Hence the outcome is a list with the names of the two excelfiles and the sheets of the respective excelfiels

```
"Customers (Sample)"  "Orders (Sample - Sales (Excel))"
```

Note: I cannot say why one data source inlcudes "(Excel)" while the other does not. 
Anyways, the desired outcome (= visualisation) would be

```
Datasource: Sample          Sheet Name: Customer
Datasource: Sample - Sales  Sheet Name: Orders
```

Question: how to tell R to "find name within () i.e. "Sample" or "Sample - Sales" and to paste this .... then to find the string within " " but outside of (), i.e. "Customer" or "Orders "?

Thanks a million for any thoughts and advice!

Answer (score 0):

list the ds object. use xml_attr to get the content.
Also post the actual file.